# How can I make this code so that only the final answer will print?

Tags: java

I need this to only display the final answer and not the answer from the first part of the code. This is because it currently displays two answers; one from the first part and one from the last part and all I need is the answer from the last part to display

```
public class Arbitrary extends ArithmeticExpression {
 Arbitrary(double value1, double value2, double value3, char operator1, char operator2){
this.value1 = value1;
this.value2 = value2;
this.value3 = value3;
this.operator1 = operator1;
this.operator2 = operator2;
}


public double evaluate(){
    System.out.println("Arbitrary Answer Is");

    if (operator1 == '+'){            // this if statement covers all the signs that may come up,if the first sign is a +, then the program will add the two numbers but if it isn't. The program will continue to go to else until it finds the correct sign or states the rror message.//
        Addition add = new Addition(value1,value2);
        result1 = add.evaluate();
    }
    else if (operator1 == '-'){
        Subtraction sub = new Subtraction(value1,value2);
        result1 = sub.evaluate();
    }
    else if (operator1 == '*'){
        Multiplication mult = new Multiplication(value1,value2);
        result1 = mult.evaluate();
    }
    else if (operator1 == '/'){
        Division div = new Division(value1,value2);
        result1 = div.evaluate();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid Sum!");
    }


    if (operator2 == '+')

             {
        Addition plus = new Addition(result1,value3);
        result2 = plus.evaluate();
            }


    else if (operator2 == '-')
    {
        Subtraction take = new Subtraction(result1,value3);
        result2 = take.evaluate();
    }
    else if (operator2 == '*'){
        Multiplication times = new Multiplication(result1,value3);
        result2 = times.evaluate();
    }
    else if (operator2 == '/'){
        Division share = new Division(result1,value3);
        result2 = share.evaluate();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Incorrect expression!");
    }

    return result2;
}

public double display() {
      System.out.println("Abitrary Question Is");
    System.out.println("("+value1 + "+" + value2+")" + " * "+ "("+value3+")");
    return result2;

}

}
```

this part is in my main:

```
Arbitrary a1 = new Arbitrary(6, 9, 2, '+', '*');
           a1.display();
           a1.evaluate();
           System.out.println();
```

this is the output i get:
Abitrary Question Is
(6.0+9.0) * (2.0)
Addition Answer Is
15.0
Multiplication Answer Is
30.0

and what i am supposed to get is:
Abitrary Question Is
(6.0+9.0) * (2.0)
Arbitrary Answer is
30.0

addition.java

```
   class Addition extends ArithmeticExpression{
Addition(double value1, double value2){
   result = value1 + value2;
   this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
}


public double display() {
    System.out.println("Addition Question Is ");
    System.out.println(value1 + " + "+ value2);
    return result;

}
public double evaluate(){
    System.out.println("Addition Answer Is");
    System.out.println(result);
return result;
}
}
```

multiplication.java

```
   class Multiplication extends ArithmeticExpression{
Multiplication(double value1, double value2){
    result = value1 * value2;
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
}



public double display() {
      System.out.println("Multiplication Question Is");
    System.out.println(value1 + " * "+ value2);
    return result;

}
public double evaluate(){
      System.out.println("Multiplication Answer Is");
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}


}
```

Comment: Where is your `main` method?  It's hard to tell which of (`evaluate`, `display`) is called to do the work.

Comment: what is the output you get and what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the classes `Addition` & `Multiplication`
i assume you print a result inside each of those (and inside the other operators also)
this causes the program to print the answer of the first action you did (which is addition)
and then the second action (which is multiplication)

in both classes, you can see that:

```
public double evaluate(){
    System.out.println("Addition Answer Is");
    System.out.println(result);
return result;
}
```

prints "Addition Answer Is" + result.

just delete (or comment out) the first 2 lines in the evaluate functions of  `Addition` & `Multiplication`

for addition:

```
System.out.println("Addition Answer Is");
System.out.println(result);
```

for Multiplication

```
   System.out.println("Multiplication Answer Is");
    System.out.println(result);
```

after you'll delete the unnecessary prints, change the code to be:

```
Arbitrary a1 = new Arbitrary(6, 9, 2, '+', '*');
           a1.display();
           System.out.println(a1.evaluate());
           System.out.println();
```

Comment: how can i get it to print the way i need it to?

Comment: search for a System.out.println("Addition Answer Is");  in Addition (and the other print in Multiplication) and delete it. or post the source of Addition & Multiplication

Comment: ive got it working thanks my question now is how can i get it to print out the different operators aswell?

Comment: @user1052425: im not sure i understand you're question. but int the Arbitrary class, display function change  System.out.println("("+value1 + "+" + value2+")" + " * "+ "("+value3+")"); to be  System.out.println("("+value1 + " " + operator1 + " " + value2+") " + operator2 + " ("+value3+")");  to fix the print for the other operators

Comment: i got it to change in the test class just changed the operations around

Comment: @user1052425 If this was the correct answer would you mind upvote + accept?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the code you provided doesn't print the answer at all, let alone print it twice.  However it does print `"Arbitrary Answer Is"` each time that evaluate is called, and that is going to look strange in the cases where it is called recursively.

So I'm going to guess that *that* it is what you are talking about.  If that is true, then the fix is to remove the println at the start of `evaluate`, and put it in the method that is calling `evaluate` ...